# Making a HTML section only visible to some people via PHP

Tags: php, html, css

I've made a section in HTML, but I want to be visible only to people who are if($Admin >= 1)  from my database.

But I don't know how to write it.

This is my HTML so far.

```
!-- ADM SECTION -->
  <div class="backimg" id="section-10">
    <div class="bghover wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1.5s" data-wow-delay=".5s">
      <div class="grid flex16">
        <div class="row paddtop5">
          <h3 class="paraw wow fadeInUpBig" data-wow-duration="2s" data-wow-delay=".5s">ADMIN SECTION</h3>

                  <div class="admin">
<h3 data-wow-duration="2s" data-wow-delay=".5s"> Alege opțiunea </h3>
</div>


<!-- ban -->
<style>
ul.b {list-style-type: square;}</style>

<div class="ban"> 
<ul class="b">
  <li>BAN SYSTEM</li>
  <br>

  <li>KICK SYSTEM</li>
  <br>

  <li>ADMIN JAIL SYSTEM</li>
  <br>  
</ul>
</div>

<div class="ban2"> 
<ul class="b">
  <li>SEARCH SYSTEM</li>
  <br>

  <li>LOG SYSTEM</li>
  <br>

  <li>AWARD SYSTEM</li>
  <br>  
</ul>
</div>

<div class="ban3"> 
<ul class="b">
  <li>MANAGAMENT SYSTEM</li>
  <br>

  <li>UNBAN SYSTEM</li>
  <br>

  <li>UNJAIL SYSTEM</li>
  <br>  
</ul>
</div>
```

Shall I add  if($Admin >= 1)  echo  ?  I want to show nothing to who has $admin lower than 1.  And who has higher or equal than 1, to show that HTML part.

Comment: You can write php condition code in your page directly if your file have save as php extension !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php if($Admin >= 1) { ?>
<!-- ADM SECTION -->


 <div class="backimg" id="section-10">
    <div class="bghover wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1.5s" data-wow-delay=".5s">
      <div class="grid flex16">
        <div class="row paddtop5">
          <h3 class="paraw wow fadeInUpBig" data-wow-duration="2s" data-wow-delay=".5s">ADMIN SECTION</h3>

                  <div class="admin">
<h3 data-wow-duration="2s" data-wow-delay=".5s"> Alege opțiunea </h3>
</div>


<!-- ban -->
<style>
ul.b {list-style-type: square;}</style>

<div class="ban"> 
<ul class="b">
  <li>BAN SYSTEM</li>
  <br>

  <li>KICK SYSTEM</li>
  <br>

  <li>ADMIN JAIL SYSTEM</li>
  <br>  
</ul>
</div>

<div class="ban2"> 
<ul class="b">
  <li>SEARCH SYSTEM</li>
  <br>

  <li>LOG SYSTEM</li>
  <br>

  <li>AWARD SYSTEM</li>
  <br>  
</ul>
</div>

<div class="ban3"> 
<ul class="b">
  <li>MANAGAMENT SYSTEM</li>
  <br>

  <li>UNBAN SYSTEM</li>
  <br>

  <li>UNJAIL SYSTEM</li>
  <br>  
</ul>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: It totally depends how you will have that *Admin* variable.

Comment: @bhansa I extract it from database, checking if an user has admin. (0 means none).

Comment: @bhansa what is difference between this and Session?

Comment: If you want to store a general check for admin sessions is fine, otherwise use the data from your table. I prefer general data to be kept in session.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [**SESSION**](http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php) variables in php. You can check for that value and put a if statement.
Where **Admin** will be one of the attributes for user in your user table.

If **truthy** show your html section.

```
if (isset($_SESSION['Admin'])) {
// show your content
}
```

Checking for Admin level:

```
if ($_SESSION['Admin'] >= 1) {
    // show your content
    }
```

Comment: Well, I need to define session "admin"  as every registred member who has admin level 1+ , no?

Comment: Yes, you will have to. That way you can have a access hierarchy of all users as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use if else in html like so

```
    <?php if ($Admin === 1) : ?>
        <h1> show admin html </h1>
    <?php else if ($Admin < 1) : ?>
        <h1> do smth else </h1>
    <?php else : ?>
        <h1> do thmth else </h1>
    <?php endif : ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your html file, you can write down like this ,

```
<?php if ( $admin>=1 ): ?>
  <div>
      Here you can put all of your html 
      code for admin.
 </div>
<?php endif;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

A Lot of imporoments have to be  done for the coding. Follow following steps.

1. Create a PHP file ex:index.php
2. Add all your HTML code within that PHP file.
3. Write following code for display this section.

   Procedure 1.

   ```
   <?php
   if($Admin > 1) {
   ?>
   //write your html code  here.
   <?php
   }
   ?>
   ```